# Updating mongo data with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

Have an application with angular and mongo.
This is part of my api, in witch i have post and put request. Post request working fine, but when i put data, i have an error "Cannot set property 'typelocal' of undefined". In postman put request works fine:

```
var Flat = require('../models/flat.js');
        .put('/realestate/flats/edit/:id', function(req, res){
            Flat.findById(req.params.id, function(err, flat){
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                flat.typelocal = req.body.typelocal;
                flat.save(function(err, flat){
                    if(err){
                        res.send(err);
                    }
                    res.json(flat);
                })
            })
        })

        .post('/realestate/flats/add', function(req, res){
            var flat = new Flat({
                    creator: req.decoded.id,
                    typelocal: req.body.typelocal,
                });
            flat.save(function(err, newFlat){
                    if(err){
                        res.send(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    // io.emit('flat', newFlat);
                    res.json({message: "New Flat Created!"});
                });
        })
    return api;
};
```

If i change my put request for:

```
.put('/realestate/flats/edit/:id', function(req, res){
   Flat.findById(req.params.id, function(err, flat){
      if(err){
         res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(flat);
   })
})
```

i have an object, for example:

```
{
  "_id": "55f51361589d7ff015c899df",
  "creator": "55ab2ee75d4c5c901f2517f9",
  "typelocal": "rrrr",
  "__v": 0,
  "created": "2015-09-13T06:10:41.054Z"
}
```

This is my html, in witch i have an input for updating data:

```
<div ng-controller="EditFlatController as flat">
    <form class="form-control">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="localtype" ng-model="flat.flatData.typelocal" placeholder="Typ lokalu" value="{{ flat.flat.typelocal }}">
        <button ng-click="flat.editFlatSave()" class="my-btn my-btn-danger rebtn-add-add">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is part of my controller:

```
.controller('EditFlatController', ['UpdateFlat', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function(UpdateFlat, $http, $location, $routeParams){
        vm = this;
        $http.get('/api/realestate/flats/edit/' + $routeParams.id).success(function(data){
            vm.flat = data;
        })
        vm.editFlatSave = function(){
            vm.message = '';
            UpdateFlat.update(vm.flatData)
                .success(function(data){
                    vm.flatData = '';
                    vm.message = data.message;
                    $location.path('/realestate/flats');
                })
        }
    }])
```

This is the Service:

```
.factory('UpdateFlat', function($http){
        var flatFactory = {};
        flatFactory.update = function(flatData){
            return $http.put('/api/realestate/flats/edit/:id', flatData);
        };
        return flatFactory;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the service

```
.factory('UpdateFlat', function($http, $routeParams){
        var flatFactory = {};
        flatFactory.update = function(flatData){
            return $http.put('/api/realestate/flats/edit/' + $routeParams.id, flatData);
        };
        return flatFactory;
    })
```